# Efficiancy of Horner's Rule to compute summation

Tags: algorithm

How is Horner's rule an efficient  method to compute summation of polynomials ?

```
int HornerRule( int array [] , unsigned int n , int x )
{

    int result =  array[n] ;

    for( int i = n - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i )
    {
      result = result *x + array[i];
    }

    return result ; 
}
```

Comment: It seems pretty obvious to me. Could you please clarify what doubts you're having?

Comment: @delnan i just want an explaination of the steps involved  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horner's Rule takes advantage of the recursive definition of exponentiation:

```
x^y = x^(y-1) * x
```

Each higher-order term is evaluated using the results of the preceding term. Suppose you have a 3rd-degree polynomial; instead of evaluating `x^3` by multiplying `x` times itself twice (2 operations), you multiply `x` times `x^2` (which you already computed for the `x^2` term), which is only 1 operation. Writing out the polynomial in a factored form,
(with coefficients of 1 for simplicity):

```
x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = x(x^2 + x) + 1
                  = x(x(x + 1)) + 1
```

(You might notice that in this case, you have the same number of multiplications, 3 on each side. As the degree increases, though, the left-hand side adds `k-1` multiplications when you add a term of degree `k`, but the right-hand side would add only a single multiplication:

```
x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = x(x^3 + x^2 + x) + 1
                        = x(x(x(x + 1)) + 1) + 1
```

)